# How to append 'null' or 'n/a' value when extracting data from Youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

My code allows to call data from Youtube API and put them into list to form a datafram.
However, when the API cannot access the 'items' it returns error. In order to avoid errors, I need to append 'n/a' or 'null' and pass when the API cannot access certain items.

```
def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_ids):
all_data = []
for i in range(0, len(channel_ids), 50):
    request = youtube.channels().list(
                part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                id = ','.join(channel_ids[i:i+50]))
    response = request.execute()

    for i in range(len(response['items'])):
        data = dict(channel_name = response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'],
                    published_date = response['items'][i]['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                    subscribers = response['items'][i]['statistics']['subscriberCount'],
                    views = response['items'][i]['statistics']['viewCount'],
                    total_videos = response['items'][i]['statistics']['videoCount'],
                    playlist_id = response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'],
                    retrieved_date = date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')              
                    )
        
        all_data.append(data)
return all_data
```

Any directions or advice would be very helpful.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this works:

```py
def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_ids):
    all_data = []
    for i in range(0, len(channel_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.channels().list(
                part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                id = ','.join(channel_ids[i:i+50]))
        response = request.execute()
        
    if resp.items:
        for i in range(len(response['items'])):
            data = dict(channel_name = response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'],
                        published_date = response['items'][i]['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                        subscribers = response['items'][i]['statistics']['subscriberCount'],
                        views = response['items'][i]['statistics']['viewCount'],
                        total_videos = response['items'][i]['statistics']['videoCount'],
                        playlist_id = response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['loads'],
                        retrieved_date = date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')              
                        )
            
            all_data.append(data)
    else:
        all_data.append('n/a')
    
    return all_data
```

All I am doing is checking if the JSON returned by `request.execute()` has something called `items`; if it does, I proceed with your for loop, and if it doesn't, I append `'n/a'` to the `all_data` list.